# How to change graphical date picker calendar settings in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a `DatePicker` with `GraphicalDatePickerStyle` set to show the new beautiful apple calendar. but how can I set the settings of the calendar? I know how to set the range. But I specifically need to change the calendar identifier.

here is how I'm passing the range of dates and the locale:

```
DatePicker(
    "Returning Date",
    selection: $returningDate,
    in: departureDate...,
    displayedComponents: .date
)
.datePickerStyle(GraphicalDatePickerStyle())
```

Answer (score 1):

> First, You should put **UIKit and Object-Oriented Thinking** aside!

A lot of settings are handled using `Environment` objects and `ViewModifiers` in the **SwiftUI**. So you should set the `calendar` as an Environment object like

```
.environment(\.calendar, .init(identifier: .persian))
```

Also, you can set the `locale` for the language of the calendar like:

```
.environment(\.locale, "fa")
```

That's it!

<sub>After 2 hours of looking for the answer in the interface</sub>